# ??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, feature-extraction, vlfeat

I am working on an image retrieval project. It requires The VLFeat open source library which implements popular computer vision algorithms specializing in image understanding and local features extraction and matching. Even after successful implementation of VLFEAT toolbox I get the following error:

```
??? Attempt to reference field of non-structure array.
Error in ==> gm at 84 locs = fq.f(1:2,:);
```

`fq` is a struct with the N query features as returned by VLFEAT: contains of two elements:

- `fq.f` is a 6xN matrix with the ellipsoids descriptors of each detected feature in the query.
- `fq.d` is a MxN matrix with the M-dimensional features descriptors of each detected feature in the query.

'fq' is an input parameter to the main function 'gm' which carries out the image retrieval task between query image and the R reference images.

```
function [similarities]= gm(query_path,reference_paths,fq,fr,matches,K)
```

Comment: explain clearly with sample data and code

Comment: Could fq be empty when there are no features?

Comment: `dbstop if error` or set a breakpoint and *check* what fq is. Just suppose it's supposed to be a struct at that point... (Navan probably has it right).

Comment: @Navan - I suspect that's the case.  We won't know for sure because we don't have any code available.